# Get list of assigned users in an Azure Virtual Desktop host pool using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I would like to get a list of users that are assigned to AVD session hosts. There are a few `Powershell` cmdlets like `Get-AzWvdWorkspace` and `Get-AzWvdHostPool`, but I don't see anything that would provide assigned users in the output.

Is there anything that I can use to provide this output without resorting to exporting each host pool in CSV and filtering assigned users within that?

Comment: Host Pools get assigned Application Groups (AVD Groups), those contain the assignments

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you. Can you expand on that, please. I used `Get-AzWvdHostPool` to determine the application group, then used `Get-AzWvdApplicationGroup` to get the information on that. I don't see anything in its properties that I can identify as being a list of assignments.

Comment: Once you have the associated AVD Group you can from there use its `.Id` to get the role assignments with `Get-AzRoleAssignment` and then you need to filter that output where the `.Scope` ends with your AVD Group Name

Comment: Ah, I'm not looking for role assignments. I was trying to sort out how to determine which user has been assigned to a session host. I found that the `Get-AzWvdSessionHost` cmdlet is what I'm looking for. It provides the `AssignedUser` property when used with a specific session host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do agree @theillien, I use the same way as below to get the assigned users and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.desktopvirtualization/get-azwvdsessionhost?view=azps-11.3.0):

```
$rithsesHosts = Get-AzWvdSessionHost -ResourceGroupName "rithwik" -HostPoolName "rithwiktest"
foreach ($rith in $rithsesHosts) {
    $rithasUser = $rith.AssignedUser
    Write-Output "Hello Rithwik Bojja!! , Session Host is: $($rith.Name), Assigned Users are: $rithasUser"
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]